# Trying to send a message if a value is set to true discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot send a message in a channel when it starts up, I'm not getting any errors but its not sending a message in the channel. (Yes it has permissions, I thought it was that at first)

```
startupmessage = True
channelid = 781433663032131607

async def on_ready():
    if startupmessage == True:
        await client.get_channel(channelid).send('bot online')
```

I tried reversing it and putting the if statement first but I got errors saying invalid syntax.

Comment: Please pay attention to correct capitalisation.

Comment: The above code works as an `on_ready` event on my side. Can you update your answer to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? For example, how is `startupmessage` and `channelid` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because tou didn't register the event.

```
startupmessage = True
channelid = 781433663032131607

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    if startupmessage == True:
        await client.get_channel(channelid).send('bot online')
```

This should be fine.